# What does Frostbite do?

Tags: dark-souls-3

I recently acquired the Irithyll Straight Sword and see that it does Frost damage. When fighting a boss, I noticed that eventually gave me Frostbite, though I have no idea what Frostbite actually does. Checking the wikis has been inconclusive, mentioning that maybe it hinders stamina regen.

What does Frostbite do? If it only slows Stamina regen, does it even matter in PVE?

Comment: I may have imagined it, but my movement seemed slower while frostbitten in the boss fight.

Answer (score 4):

What frostbite does is it fills up a bar. Once that bar is full, it does significantly damage to health, and stamina regen will decrease

Comment: This when the status effect is inflicted on a player, right? Do you have any information about how it works on non-player enemies?

Comment: @twobugs most likely the same unless they have an immunity to it such as frost creatures such as the frost knight or vordt

Answer (score 2):

It works similar to bleed, but instead of doing an insane amount of HP damage, it splits between HP and Stamina damage, reduces your stamina regen and slows your movement. Vordt has an AoE Frostbite 'aura' and the smaller Irithyll knights you find through the game also deal frostbite damage with the weapons you receive by defeating them. It's also good to note that like bleed, some bosses have a higher resistance (and those like Vordt) or complete resistance to Frostbite.